# PouchDB Load producing error

Tags: pouchdb

I'm trying to use PouchDB to load initial content into my database using the following code snippet:

```
db2.load('bloggr.txt').then(function() {
    // done loading!
}).catch(function(err) {
    // HTTP error or something like that
    console.log(err);
});
```

I'm using some of the example content provided by PouchDB Load. the database gets created, and records are created but I get a Javascript error in the console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'db_name' of undefined
at pouchdb.load.js:56
```

looking at line 56 I see the following

```
var target = new db.constructor(info.db_name,
```

Anyone have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: What code are you using to construct db2 and load the `load` plugin?

Comment: The declaration of db2 is `var db2 = new pouchDB('http://localhost:15984/quest')` since this is client side, I am just calling in the PouchDB load script after pouched.js  `<script src="bower_components/pouchdb-load/dist/pouchdb.load.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm also using angular-pouchdb which may be my problem but if that was the case I would think the load plugin wouldn't work at all rather than loading the records and erroring out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working perfect for me:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PouchDB-Load Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pouchdb/4.0.3/pouchdb.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load/master/dist/pouchdb.load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var db2 = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/pouchdb-load-test/');
    console.log('Starting load');
    db2.load('bloggr.txt')
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Success!');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // HTTP error or something like that
      console.log(err);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you have [CORS enabled](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb) in your CouchDB config. It will fail with `file://` so needs to be run from a web server.

Comment: Looks like my Bower install of PouchDB was corrupted. Using the CDN sources works without any problems. Thanks.